# Pubsub event communication between sibling components inside visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning-out

I have 2 sibling components inside a visualforce page. When i try to write pubsub events in the LWC components i am getting the below error

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [afterRender threw an error in 'c:lwcContainer' [pubsub listeners need a "@wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef" property]] Failing descriptor: {ltng:outApp}

VF Page Code

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightningvf" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:lwcvf", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:lwcContainer",
              {},
              "lightningvf",
              function(cmp) {
                console.log("button was created");
                // do some stuff
              }
          );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

i have used the below blog to create 2 lightning web components
https://www.santanuatonline.com/publish-subscriber-model-in-lightning-web-component/

How do i communicate between these 2 sibling LWC's which are residing inside the vf page?

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe use the Lightning Messaging Service instead of the LWC pubsub.

See for example https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_lc_message_channel.htm